# Novice trying to learn some music theory from an old book. Have I answered this correctly?

Tags: chord-theory, sheet-music

Good day. I'm trying to learn how to read notes from an old music theory book I borrowed from a friend.
I need to answer some questions on this paper: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VWmL.jpg
I can't find the correct answers nowhere in the book, so I hope you can help me.

- What chord is it on 10? My answer: E minor
- What chord is it on 11? My answer: A minor
- What chord is it on 12? My answer: D7
- What chord is it on 13? My answer: G major

I also need to find in what inversions they're in.
How do I do that? I don't quite understand how.

Thank you and sorry if you don't understand my questions. English is not my native language.

Comment: What is the old book?

Comment: It's a swedish book: https://www.adlibris.com/se/bok/elementar-musikteori-9789177481645

Answer (score 1):

Well done! All correct. You've worked out basic triads, and added m7 to the D making D7.

It's a bit odd, but we name inversions of chords using the *lowest* note. If it's root, then the chord's root position. 1st inversion has 3 underneath, 2nd has 5 at the bottom, etc. It really doesn't make a difference what other of the chord's notes are above, or what order, it's simply the *lowest* note that determines.

Comment: One could argue that the E at 10 is a non-chord tone and that the chord is therefore G.